# manage the result of two eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I trying to get back the selected value in the dropdown and attribute it to atom.name in order to change the atom name. By default there is ch2 molecule and when click on Na. Ch2 should be replace by Na but the problem is the scope of the event listener and the capacity to manage these two eventlistener. The one who manage the dropdown result

```
var a = document.getElementById('atomDropdown');
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
}, false);
```

the console.log give here the right result and
the eventlistener which manage the position of the dropdown menu with

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    let atom = atoms.find(a => distance(a.position, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY}) <= a.r)
    atomDropdown.classList.remove('hidden')
    if(atom){
       atomDropdown.style.left = atom.position.x + 'px'
       atomDropdown.style.top = (atom.position.y + atom.r) + 'px'
    }
    console.log(atom.name);
})
```

What I'm trying to do without success is to attribute atom.name to this value.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
  height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
  atoms = [],
  bonds = [],
  atomDropdown = document.getElementById('atomDropdown')

document.body.appendChild(canvas)

class Atom {
 constructor({ x, y, name }){
  this.position = {}
  this.position.x = x
  this.position.y = y
  this.name = name
  this.r = name.length * 10

  atoms.push(this)
 }

 draw(){
  let { position, name, r } = this,
      { x, y } = position

  context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE'
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  context.fill()


  context.fillStyle = '#000000'
  context.font = '20px sans-serif'
  context.textAlign = 'center'
  context.fillText(name, x, y + 5)
 }
}

class Bond {
 constructor({ atom1, atom2, type }){
  this.atom1 = atom1
  this.atom2 = atom2
  
  bonds.push(this)
 }
 
 draw(){
  let { atom1, atom2 } = this
  
  context.beginPath()
  context.strokeStyle = '#000000'
  context.moveTo(atom1.position.x, atom1.position.y)
  context.lineTo(atom2.position.x, atom2.position.y)
  context.stroke()
 }
}

let hexagon = {
 size: 100,
 x: width/2,
 y: height/2
}

let lastAtom

for (var side = 0; side < 7; side++) {
 let newAtom = new Atom({
  x: hexagon.x + hexagon.size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6),
  y: hexagon.y + hexagon.size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6),
  name: 'CH2'
 })
 
 if(lastAtom) new Bond({ atom1: lastAtom, atom2: newAtom })
 if(side == 6) new Bond({ atom1: newAtom, atom2: atoms[0] })
 lastAtom = newAtom
}

function render(){
 context.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF'
 context.fillRect(0,0,width,height)

 bonds.map(b => b.draw())
 atoms.map(a => a.draw())
}

render()

function distance(p1, p2){
 return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2))
}
var a = document.getElementById('atomDropdown');
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
}, false);

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
 let atom = atoms.find(a => distance(a.position, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY}) <= a.r)
 atomDropdown.classList.remove('hidden')
 if(atom){
    atomDropdown.style.left = atom.position.x + 'px'
    atomDropdown.style.top = (atom.position.y + atom.r) + 'px'
 }
 console.log(atom.name);
})
```

```css
#atomDropdown {
 position: absolute;
 
 &.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="atomDropdown" class="hidden">
 <option>Test1</option>
 <option>Test2</option>
 <option>Test3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the desired behavior is to change the value of atom.name for the atom that was clicked, replacing it with a name from the dropdown menu.

E.g., click on a CH2 atom -> select "Test1" from the dropdown menu -> the value of this.name for the atom you click changes from "CH2" to "Test1".

If that's the case, the issue is how to target the same atom from your last "mouseup" event in the "change" handler for atomDropdown. In which case, you can add a new variable in your definitions:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
atoms = [],
bonds = [],
atomDropdown = document.getElementById('atomDropdown')

var selectedAtom = null
```

set selectedAtom to the atom instance in the "mouseup" handler:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
let atom = atoms.find(a => distance(a.position, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY}) <= a.r)
atomDropdown.classList.remove('hidden')
if(atom){
   selectedAtom = atom
   atomDropdown.style.left = atom.position.x + 'px'
   atomDropdown.style.top = (atom.position.y + atom.r) + 'px'
}
console.log(atom.name);
```

})

and update selectedAtom.name in the "change event":

```
var a = document.getElementById('atomDropdown');
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (selectedAtom) {
    selectedAtom.name = this.value;
    render(); //added so that the GUI updates when the name value changes
  }
  console.log(this.value);
}, false);
```

**EDIT:** to immediately update the name of the atom as it appears in the GUI/display, you also have to call render() after selectedAtom.name is changed in atomDropDown's "change" event.

Comment: Hi esopp it's strange because I'm can change every atom except the right one : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmdWbW

Comment: It looks like there are two overlapping atoms (i.e., an extra, 7th atom drawn ontop of the first one in the same position) on the right. If you change the condition "side < 7" to "side < 6" in  `for (var side = 0; side < 7; side++) ` and "if(side == 6)" to "if(side==5)" in `if(side == 6) new Bond({ atom1: newAtom, atom2: atoms[0] })` that fixes the problem.

Comment: This is a case of find() returning only the first matching element in an array, when there are two elements that match. This happens in the "mouseup" event where atoms[0] becomes the selected atom. Since atoms[0] will be drawn first in the render() function, when atoms[6] is drawn, atoms[0] is covered up.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, you're looking to set the dropdown menu's value to atom.name?

If so, you need to add an attribute "value" to the options, then you can say something like:

```
document.getElementById("atomDropdown").value = atom.name
```

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<select id="atomDropdown" class="hidden">
    <option value="Na">Test1</option>
    <option value="Ch2">Test2</option>
    <option value="O2">Test3</option>
</select>
```